# jQuery Date picker and class assign

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using the default jquery's date picker that is triggered by assigning the `dp` class to an input element.
It works fine if i set the class of the element in the html, but if I assign the `dp` class with js (`document.getElementById(eleId).className = 'dp';`) the date picker is not triggered when the user clicks on the input.
Any idea?

Comment: Right click and check the the HTML for that element using Firebug ??

Comment: after assigning the dp class then you should call datepicker function

Comment: @rajeshkakawat yeah that's the problem! But still I have a problem, I found the jQuery function, but I have troubles calling it (I'm not really an expert...). It looks like this: `(function($,undefined){function Datepicker(){this.debug=!1,this._curInst=null,this._keyEvent`, but if i simply call `onchange="Datepicker()"` it tells me it can't find it.. Do you know haw I should call it?

Comment: could you show your code or fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when you bind the `datepicker` event to your elements (via the selector, probably `$(".dp")`, it is only bound to the ones that are found at that point in time. Any time after that, like you said, elements may gain the class (or even lose it). My suggestion would be to do something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- Your elements that may or may not have the class "dp" -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#container").on("click", "dp", function () {
        $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({showOn: 'both'}).focus();
    });
</script>
```

Where of course you can just put the binding into `document.ready`, and you can change the options passed to `datepicker`. Instead of `"#container"`, you could just use `"body"` or something if you can't narrow it down that much. Also, you'll need to account for `onfocus` too in some way.

Something I would suggest though, is to use jQuery everywhere you can, since you already include it. For example, your code: `document.getElementById(eleId).className = 'dp';` is fine, but why not use the method `addClass`, and why not use the `"#"` selector? Like:

```
$("#" + eleId).addClass("dp");
// and alternatively
$("#" + eleId).removeClass("dp");
```

A problem with using `className` is that it isn't as easy to manipulate the class of the element. Using `.className = "whatever"` overwrites any previous `className` value - of course, you can account for that, but it's easier to just use jQuery for this. Also, when using `removeClass`, jQuery may or may not automatically remove any event bindings for the element, where `className` does nothing like that. If you were to do things like removing and adding classes, it could get messy.

Comment: I've tried to use your code (updating the id container), but unfortunately it did not work... Am I missing something that I should update as well?

Comment: @ghego1 You're going to have to elaborate on "but unfortunately it did not work". Did you try using `console.log` to see if things were being executed and tried debugging? Did you change the `"#container"` selector to what it should be in your code?

Answer (score 0):

It matters when the class is assigned. You have to assign the class *before* you load up the datepicker module.

Otherwise, the datepicker loads up any inputs it find, then stops. If you assign the class AFTER that event, there won't be any response since the loader has done its job and is not interested in any new items.

Alternatively, you can call the datepicker again, *after* you assign the class to the element.